# Finding Optimal Parameters In A "Black Box" System

Tags: optimization, parameters, machine-learning

I'm developing machine learning algorithms which classify images based on training data.

During the image preprocessing stages, there are several parameters which I can modify that affect the data I feed my algorithms (for example, I can change the Hessian Threshold when extracting SURF features). So the flow thus far looks like:

[param1, param2, param3...] => [black box] => accuracy %

My problem is: **with so many parameters at my disposal, how can I systematically pick values which give me optimized results/accuracy?** A naive approach is to run i nested for-loops (assuming i parameters) and just iterate through all parameter combinations, but if it takes 5 minute to calculate an accuracy from my "black box" system this would take a long, long time.

This being said, are there any algorithms or techniques which can search for optimal parameters in a black box system? I was thinking of taking a course in Discrete Optimization but I'm not sure if that would be the best use of my time.

Thank you for your time and help!

**Edit** (to answer comments):
I have 5-8 parameters. Each parameter has its own range. One parameter can be 0-1000 (integer), while another can be 0 to 1 (real number). Nothing is stopping me from multithreading the black box evaluation.

Also, there are some parts of the black box that have some randomness to them. For example, one stage is using k-means clustering. Each black box evaluation, the cluster centers may change. I run k-means several times to (hopefully) avoid local optima. In addition, I evaluate the black box multiple times and find the median accuracy in order to further mitigate randomness and outliers.

Comment: How many parameters, and what value ranges can they have? Also is it possible to multithread your blackbox evaluation, e.g. with a (cloud) computing cluster?

Comment: Thanks for your questions! I revised the original question with the answers.

Answer (score 2):

As a partial solution, a grid search of moderate resolution and range can be *recursively* repeated in the areas where the n-parameters result in the optimal values.

Each n-dimensioned result from each step would be used as a *starting* point for the next iteration.

The key is that for each iteration the resolution in absolute terms is kept constant (i.e. keep the iteration period constant) but the range *decreased* so as to reduce the pitch/granular step size.

I'd call it a ‘contracting mesh’ :)

Keep in mind that while it avoids full brute-force complexity it only reaches exhaustive resolution in the final iteration (this is what **defines** the final iteration).

Also that the outlined process is only exhaustive on a subset of the points that may or may not include the global minimum - i.e. *it could result in a local minima.*

(You can always chase your tail though by offsetting the initial grid by some sub-initial-resolution amount and compare results...)

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [solution](https://github.com/paulknysh/blackbox) to your problem.

A method behind it is described in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.00998.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide some context for your links.  If the links die in the future, so does the usefulness of the answer.  See [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).